# Python variadic generics accepting class

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, variadic-tuple-types

[a variable annotated with Type[C] may accept values that are classes themselves](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)

How do you do this with [TypeVarTuples (PEP 646)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#type-variable-tuples)

```py
from typing import TypeVar, TypeVarTuple

T = TypeVar("T")
Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

def foo(a: T) -> T:
    ...
def bar(a: type[T]) -> T:
    ...
def baz(*a: *Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]:
    ...

a = foo(int) # type[int]
b = bar(int) # int
c = baz(int, str) # tuple[type[int], type[str]]

# What syntax?
def qux(*a: type[*Ts]) -> tuple[*Ts]: 
    ...
d = qux(int, str) # should be tuple[int, str]
```

Comment: @Axe319 Sorry yes I've updated the question

Comment: Possibly related [github issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216).