# Type hinting instances vs types with variadic generics

Tags: python, generics, types, variadic-functions, type-hinting

This is a question for the type hinting pros among you.
I have the following construct and I'm wondering if there is a way to corrctly add type annotations to it as it is. This is from the Qt framework if anyone is wondering.

There is a `Slot()` decorator, that accepts a variable number of types.
Those types must match the decorated methods' signature minus the self parameter.
Right now, this is not checked and that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

QtCore.pyi:

```py
class Slot(object):
    def __init__(self, *types: type, name: Optional[str] = ..., result: Optional[str] = ...) -> None: ...
    def __call__(self, function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]: ...
```

Usage:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot

class C:
    @Slot(str, int)  # these arguments must match number and type of arguments of foo()
    def foo(self, text: str, num: int) -> None:
        print(f"{text.lower()}, {num.__abs__()}")

C().foo("ABC", -123)
```

---

**What I tried so far**
I got it to work for a single or fixed number of types. Altough not very elegantly, using 3 TypeVars.

```py
T_arg = TypeVar('T_arg')
T_self = TypeVar('T_self')
T_ret = TypeVar('T_ret')

class Slot(Generic[T_arg]):
    def __init__(self, types: Type[T_arg], name: Optional[str] = ..., result: Optional[str] = ...) -> None: ...
    def __call__(self, function: Callable[[T_self, T_arg], T_ret]) -> Callable[[T_self, T_arg], T_ret]: ...
```

Then i tried to extend this to work with a variable number of parameters, using a TypeVarTuple for T_arg. And that's the part i couldn't get to work as i intended.

```py
T_args = TypeVarTuple('T_args')
T_self = TypeVar('T_self')
T_ret = TypeVar('T_ret')

class Slot(Generic[*T_args]):
    def __init__(self, types: Type[*T_args], name: Optional[str] = ..., result: Optional[str] = ...) -> None: ...
    def __call__(self, function: Callable[[T_self, *T_args], T_ret]) -> Callable[[T_self, *T_args], T_ret]: ...
```

Now obviously this part `types: Type[*T_args]` is wrong, but I hope it conveys my intention.

Is it possible to get this working using type annotations or does this require a custom plugin for the type checker?

---

**Edit:**
Found a related question: [Python variadic generics accepting class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150890/python-variadic-generics-accepting-class)

Looks like this might be a planned feature for the typing module:
https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216