How can I convert a TypeVarTuple to a ParamSpec?
(I am almost certain the wording of the question does not make sense, but I have yet to find a better one.)
I have the following code that I want to type-check:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, TypeVarTuple

C = TypeVar("C")
T = TypeVar("T")
Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

class Decorator1(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, /, type: type[T]) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, function: Callable[[C, T], None], /) -> Callable[[C, T], None]:
        return function

class DecoratorNa(Generic[T]):
    # Q: how to prevent "T" from becoming "object" here?
    def __init__(self, /, *type: type[T]) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, function: Callable[[C, T], None], /) -> Callable[[C, T], None]:
        return function

class DecoratorNb(Generic[*Ts]):
    def __init__(self, /, *types: *Ts) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    # Q: how to convert "*Ts" from "type[int], type[str]" to "int, str" here?
    def __call__(
        self, function: Callable[[C, *Ts], None], /
    ) -> Callable[[C, *Ts], None]:
        return function

class MyClass:
    # This is given and supposed to type-check:
    @Decorator1(int)
    def print_number(self, number: int) -> None: ...

    @Decorator1(str)
    def print_string(self, string: str) -> None: ...

    # # This is supposed to error:
    # @Decorator1(int)
    # def print_another_string(self, string: str) -> None: ...

    # This is supposed to type-check:
    @DecoratorNa(int, str)
    def print_number_and_string_a(self, number: int, string: str) -> None: ...

    # This is supposed to type-check:
    @DecoratorNb(int, str)
    def print_number_and_string_b(self, number: int, string: str) -> None: ...

The constructor of Decorator accepts one (or more) types at runtime (compare PySide6.QtCore.Slot()), and the decorated function is supposed to accept one (or more) parameters of that type.
This works fine with a single type using type[T], yet I fail to find the same thing for multiple types. I tried *type: type[T] but that evaluates to T = object. With a TypeVarTuple, I end up not seeing how I can convert *Ts to something like a ParamSpec. I know typing.get_args, but I am not sure how this is supposed to be applied at type-check time.

Duplicates: Type hint for an object that can be used as a type hint itself, Using TypeVarTuple with inner TypeVar (variadic generics transformation). You are trying to do two things: Annotating a type form and applying transformations on TypeVarTuples, both of which have yet to be possible.

I think the most relevant duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234660/type-hinting-instances-vs-types-with-variadic-generics, as well as https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216. In fact, I am working closely to Qt's Slot() function.

As mentioned in the comments, the exact syntax you're using doesn't currently work. Type forms, which allow type-checkers to make sense of call expressions which accept types (DecoratorNa(int, str)) are currently being submitted and are in the final stages of revision1, but as of today, there is nothing concrete for TypeVarTuple transformation.
However, if you're willing to switch syntax from a __call__ (DecoratorNa(int, str)) to a __getitem__ (DecoratorN[int, str]) expression, the following may work for you (mypy Playground, Pyright Playground):
...

from types import MethodType

...

class DecoratorN(Generic[*Ts]):
    def __init__(
        self, function: Callable[[Any, *Ts], None], /
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._function = function

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: type[Any], /) -> Callable[[*Ts], None]:
        return MethodType(self._function, instance)  # type: ignore[return-value]


class MyClass:
    # This is given and supposed to type-check:
    @Decorator1[int]
    def print_number(self, number: int) -> None: ...

    @Decorator1[str]
    def print_string(self, string: str) -> None: ...

    @Decorator1[int]  # error
    def print_another_string(self, string: str) -> None: ...

    @DecoratorN[int, str]
    def print_number_and_string(self, number: int, string: str) -> None: ...

mc: MyClass = MyClass()
mc.print_number(1)
mc.print_number("")  # error
mc.print_string("")
mc.print_string(1)  # error
mc.print_number_and_string(1, "")
mc.print_number_and_string("", 1)  # error

Here, the square brackets allow proper interpretation as type parameterisation on the DecoratorN[*Ts] type, which is then used to enforce that the decorated function has the same argument types (*Ts).
If you do not like the idea of having instances of DecoratorN, and you need to preserve the original instance method type (as in your example in the question), you can do something like this (incomplete implementation):
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    class DecoratorN(Generic[*Ts]): ...
else:
    class _DecoratorNType:
        def __getitem__(self, /, *types_):
            return type(self)(*types_)
        
        def __call__(self, function):
            return function

    DecoratorN = _DecoratorNType()



Pyright already has experimental support (see https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/pull/8875)


Thanks! Unfortunately, switching syntax is not possible - I am looking to type-annotate Qt's Slot() decorator

@bers That doesn't seem like an issue In principle, as you can just write a thin wrapper over PySide6.QtCore.Slot, as in the incomplete implementation given in the latter part of the answer. Of course, if you already have a large codebase, that'd be a rather major refactor.

...Actually, no typing solution would help if you don't want to adapt third-party code with your own implementations, right? I suppose you're using .pyi stubs generated from https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tools/pyside-genpyi.html, in which case such stubs would already have types that can't be modified. Even if you didn't want to change the syntax, and type forms and TypeVarTuple transforms worked with round brackets (), you'd have to write some kind of substitute typing interface over PySide6's existing types to get it to work.
